# Post the only modify input field php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here I have 10 input field. Then when the user click submit button I want the only input field that have been modify send to database and update rather than all input field sent to the database.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: you can use [update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Comment: What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to save the fields that the user touched, see the first variant. But a downside is that if the user changed the filed "abc" to "xyz" and then changed it to "abc", then the field will be marked as changed. If this is not what you want, then see the next variant.

(1)

You can use `onchange()` event in your field to set a variable when the field is modified. Then send these variables to the server using `input hidden` fields. Like this:

```
<input type='text' name='input1' onchange="getElementsByName('input1changed')[0].value = 1;">
<input type='text' name='input2' onchange="getElementsByName('input2changed')[0].value = 1;">

<input type='hidden' name='input1changed' value=0>
<input type='hidden' name='input2changed' value=0>
```

Then in your PHP code:

```
if ($_POST['input1changed'])
   store $_POST['input1']

if ($_POST['input2changed'])
   store $_POST['input2']
```

(2)

```
<input type='hidden' name='input1old' value='sometext1'>
<input type='text'   name='input1'    value='sometext1'>

<input type='hidden' name='input2old' value='sometext2'>
<input type='text'   name='input1'    value='sometext2'>
```

and in PHP:

```
if ($_POST['input1old'] != $_POST['input1'])
    store $_POST['input1']

if ($_POST['input2old'] != $_POST['input2'])
    store $_POST['input2']
```

Comment: Any example?Because i kind of new.

Comment: U should add backend validation as well. What if the user does not use javascript? (or its a bot)

Comment: Second variant does not use JavaScript, and is probably the best option.

Comment: This is fine. It just seems a little unnecessary. If you don't have the hidden values then there's nothing to post, so nothing to update!?!?

Comment: @Strawberry Do you mean that Submit should be disabled while there is no difference between old and new values?

Comment: Hm, I suppose we should clarify how exactly the form gets populated in the first place.

Comment: @Strawberry I think either from PHP, and then no problem to repeat the values. Or manually coding, again no problem to have two fields where they now have one.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the 2 arrays.

The first one is the data you loaded on the website and the second one the `$_POST` array.

Answer (score -1):

You can check in your php if the input is set and write a query accordingly.

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
<!-- query -->
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. OP only wants to update changed data, this does not do this

Comment: Yes, he can check if they are set and write the upgrade query accordingly

Comment: Then u should add this as answer as well :)

Comment: @DarkBee its already in the answer :P right above the code